# Parsing text area line that comma separated using Jquery or Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea with data like this (UserId,Name,Gender), and I want to parsing that data

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="data" rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="ID's Phones Number:" name="msg">097544,markd amm,male
731490,Hossam Hassan,male
130578,Kamal Eldin,male
87078148,Muhammad Ahmad Atia,male
932484,Alia AlHorria,female
093779,Yaser Hadidi,male
39393,Soka Dą,female
</textarea>
```

i want all IDs only , Names only And i want to get Names&Gender from text area above ,
i tried to separated this data but if failed .
This my JS code :

```
  var data = $('#data').val();
  console.log(fbdata[0]);
```

Comment: `data.split("\n").map(row => row.split(","))` will produce an array of arrays of strings. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it like this.

```js
var results = [];
var data = $('#data').val().trim();

if(data) {
  // Create an array by splitting the textarea.value by newline
  data = data.split(/\r?\n/);
 
  // Loop through indivdual rows, and split by comma / ,
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var temp = data[i].trim();

    if(temp) {
      // Create an array from the values in the current line
      temp = temp.split(",");

      // Separate the first and last names
      var pairs = temp[1].split(/ (.*)/s);
      
      // if there's no last name, pairs[1]
      // will be undefined, so we set it to
      // and empty string, to avid errors
      if(typeof pairs[1] === 'undefined') {
        pairs[1] = '';
      }

      var personsObj = {};
      personsObj.id = temp[0];
      personsObj.firstName = pairs[0].trim();
      personsObj.lastName = pairs[1].trim();
      personsObj.gender = temp[2].trim();
      
      results.push(personsObj);
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="data" rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="ID's Phones Number:" name="msg">097544,markd amm,male
731490,Hossam Hassan,male
130578,Kamal Eldin,male
87078148,Muhammad Ahmad Atia,male
932484,Alia AlHorria,female
093779,Yaser Hadidi,male
39393,Soka Dą,female
</textarea>
```

---

***EDIT***

If you want to replace the contents of the textarea with specific values from the processed array of objects (`results`, in my example), you could do that like this.

Please note that you do not need extra textareas, like in the following example. I am using them to show you what you would get for different combinations. In reality, you would replace the contents of the `#data` element with the new content.

```js
var results = [];
var data = $('#data').val().trim();

if(data) {
  // Create an array by splitting the textarea.value by newline
  data = data.split(/\r?\n/);
 
  // Loop through indivdual rows, and split by comma / ,
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var temp = data[i].trim();

    if(temp) {
      // Create an array from the values in the current line
      temp = temp.split(",");

      // Separate the first and last names
      var pairs = temp[1].split(/ (.*)/s);
      
      // if there's no last name, pairs[1]
      // will be undefined, so we set it to
      // and empty string, to avid errors
      if(typeof pairs[1] === 'undefined') {
        pairs[1] = '';
      }

      var personsObj = {};
      personsObj.id = temp[0];
      personsObj.firstName = pairs[0].trim();
      personsObj.lastName = pairs[1].trim();
      personsObj.gender = temp[2].trim();
      
      results.push(personsObj);
    }
  }
}

// This doesn't have to be here, you can use the logic in the loop above
// which would a better, more efficient way of doing it
// I'm doing this separately, so you can better understand how it works
// That's why there are 6 additional textareas - in reality, you would
// change the contents of your original textarea

var tmpNames = "", tmpIdsNames = "",
tmpGenders = "", tmpIdsGenders = "",
tmpNamesGenders = "", tmpIdsNamesGenders = "";

for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    tmpNames += results[i].firstName+ "\r\n";
  tmpIdsNames += results[i].id + "," + results[i].firstName + "\r\n";
  tmpGenders += results[i].gender + "\r\n";
  tmpIdsGenders += results[i].id + "," + results[i].gender + "\r\n";
  tmpNamesGenders += results[i].firstName + "," + results[i].gender + "\r\n";
  tmpIdsNamesGenders += results[i].id + "," + results[i].firstName + "," + results[i].gender + "\r\n";
}

$("#justNames").val(tmpNames);
$("#idsNames").val(tmpIdsNames);
$("#justGenders").val(tmpGenders);
$("#idsGenders").val(tmpIdsGenders);
$("#namesGenders").val(tmpNamesGenders);
$("#idsNamesGenders").val(tmpIdsNamesGenders);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
.results {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.results textarea {
  min-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="display:block; width:100%">Original data
<textarea class="form-control" id="data" rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="ID's Phones Number:" name="msg">097544,markd amm,male
731490,Hossam Hassan,male
130578,Kamal Eldin,male
87078148,Muhammad Ahmad Atia,male
932484,Alia AlHorria,female
093779,Yaser Hadidi,male
39393,Soka Dą,female
</textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">Just names
<textarea style="display:block" id="justNames" name="justNames"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">IDs and names
<textarea style="display:block" id="idsNames" name="idsNames"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">Just genders
<textarea style="display:block" id="justGenders" name="justGenders"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">IDs and genders
<textarea style="display:block" id="idsGenders" name="idsGenders"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">Names and genders
<textarea style="display:block" id="namesGenders" name="namesGenders"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="results">IDs, names and genders
<textarea style="display:block" id="idsNamesGenders" name="idsNamesGenders"></textarea>
</label>
```

You can also experiment with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26uqrytf/).

Comment: Sidenote: Going with the presumption that `.split(/ (.*)/)` will get you *names* or  *surnames* is plain wrong.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No, this is extracting just the first name. The other parts of the name are within `pairs[1]`, and are added to the `personsObj.lastName`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway what with persons that have two or more names and three surnames and a middle name? It's not your job to do guess-work.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Everything is dumped into `personsObj.lastName`. Since we don't know the original contextual ordering of the contents, we can only assume - which is what the code does. Admittedly, not a good thing to do in general, but I think it's OK in this case.

Comment: @FiddlingAway it's never OK to presume - specially never anything about person names.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, of course, but with limited information and some pre-digested data, would it be better not to do anything related to the `fullName` (let's call it that), other than to leave it as it is? Not being contrary, mind you, just wondering.

Comment: Once name/middle/second/surname/etc are joined as one single string - it's already too late. Either have them already mapped as key/value pairs - or **do nothing at all** about that string. That's the golden rule. Also to remind you that OP did *not* asked specifically for such subdivision, but just to eventually get `name` and by name is obviously meant the full **entire** *name*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Points taken.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to post another post to get the first name only and it saved me time
But the code shows an **Erorr** when the number of data lines is more than 100 lines `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`  , and this is an example [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8mo6xdj)

Comment: @egam321 This happens because one of the name entries contains only one word. To overcome this, try the following (I'll also edit the answer after). Right after declaring the `pairs` variable, add this: `if(typeof pairs[1] === 'undefined') { pairs[1] = '';}` By doing that, we're saying - if there is no last name, set it to an empty string, and then continue doing what you would normally do.

Answer (score 4):

Split your trimmed string by newlines to create an array of strings.
Then, depending on the desired output use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const elData = document.querySelector("#data");

const str = elData.value.trim();
const lines = str.split(/\n/);

// Example 1: create array or data objects

const list = lines.map(str => {
  const [id, name, gender] = str.split(",");
  return {id, name, gender};
});

// console.log(list); // get 'em all
console.log(list[1]); // get by index
// Log only names
list.forEach((user) => {
  console.log(user.name);
});

// example 2: create Object of items - by ID

const listById = lines.reduce((acc, str) => {
  const [id, name, gender] = str.split(",");
  acc[id]= {id, name, gender};
  return acc;
}, {});

// console.log(listById); // get 'em all
console.log(listById[731490]) // Get specific by ID
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="data" name="msg">097544,markd amm,male
731490,Hossam Hassan,male
130578,Kamal Eldin,male
87078148,Muhammad Ahmad Atia,male
932484,Alia AlHorria,female
093779,Yaser Hadidi,male
39393,Soka Dą,female
</textarea>
```

Comment: how can i get only names or gender into ul ?

Comment: Added an example... Please, next time if there's something unrelated to the question and you're stuck at a new problem — you should Ask a New Question.

Comment: i don't want exactly put it in ul , i just want to print only names not array , i just wnat loop it

Comment: Added an example that prints out only the names.

Answer (score 0):

See [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var data = $('#data').val().split("\n").map(line => line.split(",")[0]);
// ['097544', '731490', '130578', '87078148', '932484', '093779', '39393']
```

Comment: it works but i want loop it in ul